# Face blurs in light?

Tags: single-word-requests

When stepping under a bright light, I see that the light kind of starts to invade your face, so to speak. Is there a specific word for this?

I've tried looking for it, but have received unfavorable responses from searches. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Trying to understand your context. Is this the experience of light shining down on *your* face from your perspective or you seeing light shining down on someone else's face?

Comment: The latter. From a perspective where you are lower than the person who stepped under the light.

Comment: Is it about 'floaters & flashes'?

Comment: You may be ***dazzled*** by the light.

Comment: @FoolYup; Thanks for the clarification. I am unaware of the phenomenon. It may be that *your own* eyes cannot focus easily or correctly on a bright new object such as a face. Being dazzled as well as floaters and flashes are experiences of the one whose face is being illuminated.

Comment: You see the person in a different (and possibly less favourable) light. A lighting effect. Possibly better asked on Photography.SE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

" It may be that your own eyes cannot focus easily or correctly on a bright new object such as a face. Being dazzled as well as floaters and flashes are experiences of the one whose face is being illuminated." — Elliot, Ram, and Jim. Thank you.